# "PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: ;" Can anyone spot the error in my code?

Tags: pls-00103

I'm following an Oracle guide call 'Adventure Travel' and in the guide it says to create this procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE
add_country_for_activity(p_activity_num AT_COUNTRY_ACTIVITIES.activity_num%TYPE,p_country_id AT_COUNTRY_ACTIVITIES.country_id%TYPE)
IS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO AT_COUNTRY_ACTIVITIES (country_id,activity_num) VALUES (p_country_id,p_activity_num);
END;
```

but when I view this procedure in the Apex object browser, it says it has the "expecting ;..." error. Can anyone see where the error is in this code? Thanks in advance.